# How to deal with localization in angular app

Tags: html, angular, web, server

How do people usually deal with localization in their angular apps?

Database with translations,
or JSON files?

I've been looking into ngx-translate in angular, and how are you supposed to maintain the JSON files if it is on a server?

Comment: Have you tried [Internationalization (i18n)](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)?